# Can you make all Wordpress pages Private simultaneously without a plugin?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a Wordpress installation with thousands of pages that are all public which I need to make private. I can't use a plugin to help me; I need to do it using Wordpress' built in Public/Protected/Private paradigm.

Ideally, I would run a search and replace on an SQL export of the database. Alternatively, I would be willing to write a PHP script to handle it.

It is not an option to make all pages private manually - I am looking for a programmatic method for dealing with this problem.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just set them to private in the database, using the following query:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_status` = 'private';
```

This would set **all** posts to private, I guess you won't really use that query.

Instead, to only set articles to 'private' use:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_status` = 'private' WHERE `post_type` = 'post';
```

and to only disable pages, use:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_status` = 'private' WHERE `post_type` = 'page';
```

Post-revisions have the status 'inherit' and thus get the right inherited from the parent page or article.

Comment: Is there any such way I can edit the 'Visibility' of a page without editing it's 'Status'? (http://en.support.wordpress.com/pages/page-visibility/)

Comment: @Khior I guess that's the same. I've tried to set an article from 'public' to 'private' in the backend and the status switched in the database.

Comment: It would be good to know exactly how Visibility is set (there must be some distinction in the data between the two) but the status method will work for my purposes. Thank you =)

Answer (score 1):

As Feeela said: you can run query directly on the table, or you can use WP function like:

using `have_post` and `the_post`

```
    $my_posts['ID'] = get_the_ID();
    $my_posts['post_status']  = 'private';
    $my_posts['post_type'] = 'page';
    wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_status` = 'private' WHERE `post_type`='page';
```

This query will only set  the pages to private

Answer (score 0):

Here the Steps to make WordPress page private.

> - Go to Page. Click Add New option. For editing the old Pages, go to    pages> All Posts and find the existing Page you’d like to edit.
> - Find the Visibility and click on Edit. Select the Private option and Click    OK.
> - Click on Publish.